# Delve is not currently available

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, delve

We want to start using Delve in our organization but we are not able to install it from Microsoft Store. When we navigate to this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/store/p/delve/9nblggh4n0bv?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0) windows Store says that the app is not currently available. I'm the only who can use the UWP Delve app because I installed it in February'17. We are in the Spanish market.

Our users are able to install and use the app from Android and IOS devices but not from Windows computers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot your issue as following:

1. Check that you allow your organization to access the Office Graph.
2. Check that you’re using an Office 365 plan that supports Delve.
3. Check that you’ve assigned the correct user licenses.

More information refer to the article below:

[Office Delve for Office 365 admins](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-Delve-for-Office-365-admins-54f87a42-15a4-44b4-9df0-d36287d9531b)

Answer (score 0):

Checking the documentation linked before I've found the cause because we can't install Delve on Windows:

[Office Delve for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-Delve-for-Windows-9c9bf9a1-2ee9-41ab-ba68-6491c22913eb)

Seems that the app is not longer supported, I don't understand how this good Microsoft app is available for Android and iOS but not for Windows.